# Trouble with drawing a pixel through Draw_Pixel() of SDL_Draw library

Tags: visual-c++, drawing, sdl, pixel

It might sound a little strange, but I can't correctly use the Draw_Pixel() and Draw_Line() functions of SDL_Draw.h
I've googled and people state: It's very simple to use, but unfortunately... not for me.
I've written a very simple piece of code but it doesn't show me the pixel, I tried also with a line, but nothing as well.

The simple code is:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include "SDL_draw.h"     
   int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        SDL_Surface* surf;
        if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        if((surf = SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGTH, BBP, FLAGS)) == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
    Uint32 myColor = SDL_MapRGB( surf->format, 255, 25, 23); //this is the red color
        Draw_Pixel(surf, 45, 45, myColor);
        Draw_Line(surf, 45, 20, 90, 100, myColor);

        SDL_Quit();

        return 1;
    }
```

The x,y coordinates are just random. I'm trying to see the result with breakpoints in Visual Studio.

Can anyone tell me where I'm mistaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your surface by calling [SDL_Flip( SDL_Surface * screen)](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlflip.html) ;

And add a delay before exiting the program, otherwise you wont see the window.

Comment: I was under the impression that something simple was missing, but as a beginner I didn't know what. Thank you very very much! It works now!